# open one php page from other

Tags: php

i am trying to develop a website and i want that after entering correct username and password desired page should open. how i can achieve this.

Comment: The website works, if the answer was a solution, mark it as accepted, if people encounter similar problems you've experienced, they will not know what the solution is because you haven't marked any answers as accepted.

Comment: Out of 11 (unclosed) questions you have asked, you have marked 0 as accepted. This defeats the whole purpose of SO and unless you start doing so, you most likely will stop getting answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(...)
{
    // code to verify login...
    header("Location: http://page_to_forward_to/");
}
else { ... }
```

Hope this is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

```
$url = "my/url/here";
Header("Location: $url");
exit();
```

Comment: +1 for `exit()` after `header()`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `header` function:

```
 header("location: www.example.com/yourpage.php");
```

Other possibility is to use javascript:

```
<script>
  window.location = 'yourpage.php';
</script>
```